# Firebase realtime database data retrieve callback function is never called on OS X

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
ref.child("leaderboard").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
          // Get user value
          let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

          // ...
          }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
```

this code works fine on iOS, but when I ported it to OS X, the callback is never called.

Comment: Do you get any log or something?

Comment: There's no error log

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer myself. When there's no network connection, the callback doesn't called. I just need to enable outgoing connection in capability (when create a new Mac OS project, it's unchecked)

[image]